# What is the behavior of click event bound on SVG group element yet triggered on child element and completed on another?

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events

To make my question straightforward, here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/542afcfg/1/

```js
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    alert('Clicked!');
});
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <g id="parent">
        <g id="child1">
            <circle r="20" cx="40" cy="80"></circle>
        </g>
        <g id="child2">
            <circle r="20" cx="40" cy="40"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

If you start by clicking on any given child circle, and release on the other, Chrome decides that it makes sense to fire the click event while Firefox and Safari do not.

I feel since the children are grouped by the g parent element, it should fire the click event.

Anyone know what the spec says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec is easy to find.  [You can read it here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/)

> "The click event occurs when the pointing device button is clicked
>   over an element. A click is defined as a mousedown and mouseup over
>   the same screen location."

Confirmed and filed as a bug in Chromium:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424969

Comment: I'm not sure that answers my question. That definition of click event seems to allow both possible cases in my example.

Comment: I don't agree.  The way I read this, it means the mousedown and mouseup should occur within a small tolerance of each other (ie a few pixels) and over the same element.  To me, Chrome has the wrong behaviour.

Comment: Well with HTML elements, the behavior is consistent with what you mentioned across browsers. Not sure about the pixels, but Firefox and Safari seem to believe the same. Semantically the 'g' element is supposed to group its containing elements into one logical element so that's why I'm not confident. I'll see if I can confirm.